# In Mavericks, how can I make Paste and Match Style the default for Cmd-V?

Tags: macos

The instructions for Mountain Lion and other OSs do not seem to apply to Mavericks.

Comment: I gave up trying to do it at the OS level and have embraced using Flycut to strip all formatting instead. https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12

Comment: Love Flycut. Love software that does one thing well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it may not work in **all** applications there is a way of doing this for a large number. Certainly it works in `Pages`, `Numbers` and `TextEdit` but not Microsoft Word, where you have to do it within the application.

All you need to do is open `System Preferences` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` and select `App Shortcuts` in the left hand pane. Click on `All Applications` in the right hand pane and the `+` at the bottom.

In the `Menu Title` field enter `Paste and Match Style` then click in the `Keyboard Shortcut` field and press <kbd>command-V</kbd>. Then click on `Add`

You will now see that your shortcut is added. When you open `Pages`, for example, you will see that `Paste` no longer has a shortcut (you could add one using the same method) and right next to `Paste and Match Style` in the `Edit` menu is your new working shortcut,<kbd>command-V</kbd>. Oh, frabjous joy!

Answer (score 2):

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences -dict-add NSUserKeyEquivalents "Paste and Match Style" -string "@v”
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the following command to maximize the current window in macOS Mojave (10.14):

```
defaults write -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Zoom" "@\$m";
```

so, I suppose this must work in your case:

```
defaults write -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Paste and Match Style" "@\$v";
```

for other keys use:

```
Command: @
Control: ^
Option: ~
Shift: $
Tab: \U21e5 (Unicode code point for ⇥ character)
```