# How to change OSX System (Default) Shortcuts?

Tags: keyboard, macos, defaults, shortcut-menu

In OSX *(now is Mavericks)*, how to change the **System Default** Shortcuts, for example which are currently like:

- `Command + Shift + Q` .. for current **User Logout**.
- `Command + Q` .. for current (active) **Application Quit**.
- `Command + Down Arrow` .. for **Opening A File**.

Blah blah .. I don't like any of those, honestly.

- How to permanently change them, please?

*(I would even PAY for an App if it the only way to do.)*
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mind leaving the old shortcuts active?

Comment: omg dear, `changing` means i do not want the current ones to be functioning (or) do not want to use :S

Comment: I see the point of @grgarside's question. Changing (ALSO enabling _let's say_ alt-k for copy, formerly cmd-c) may not mean replacing (cmd-c then doing nothing). Could you clarify the question?

Comment: Thanks but I think i used `How to change` in the title of my question :(

Comment: As of Mojave, BetterTouchTool is the way to go  IMO

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty easy. I already answered a similar question for someone who wanted to redefine <kbd>Command-V</kbd> [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118459/in-mavericks-how-can-i-make-paste-and-match-style-the-default-for-cmd-v/118465#118465).

Basically you need to go into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts and define a new shortcut under "All Apps". If you don't want to change it to something useful you will have to define a shortcut you will never use such as <kbd>Shift-Command-Option-1</kbd>.

If you want to get rid of **all** the shortcuts then I suggest 'Karabiner-Elements' and spend some time understanding how to write a private.xml config file for it. You might also want to grab a copy of 'Key Codes' so you can figure out which keys push out which keycodes and modifiers.

It's certainly possible to map the "Log Out …" as <kbd>Shift-Command-Q</kbd> out of the way. You just enter it into Shortcuts with the name and the ellipsis and the shortcut no longer works. <kbd>Command-Q</kbd> is impossible with the shortcut method but it was the only one I could find.

(I also wouldn't be rude and peremptory to people who were trying to help me but that could just be me.)

Comment: Thank you but NOT usable for All System-wide Shortcuts. What about `Command + Shift + Q` .. for current User Logout. And, `Command + Q` .. for quitting current active application.

Answer (score 1):

Go into System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, select Accessibility on left Pane and check "Invert colors" shortcut. Initially it's disabled.

Modify it to command+Q so from now this shortcut will not close anymore apps, it will just invert colors. It's an easy way to get rid of the habit to hit command+Q.